# How can I find the shortest cycle in an undirected bipartite graph using BFS ?

Tags: graph, cycle, breadth-first-search, bipartite, shortest

How can I find the shortest cycle in a simple (not directed ) bipartite graph using Breadth First Search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bipartite graph, the shortest possible circle is at least 4 edges long. Since you are using breadth first search you will find the optimum quite fast as long as you increase your travel distance accordingly. All possible 4 edges long path, all possible 5 edges long paths, and so on. The moment you find a path that is a circle, you are done, it is the shortest possible or at least tied for that prize.

Keep all paths explored as to only increase these by 1 more edge each cycle of the search. And use BFS to make sure you have explored all paths.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Of course, you can't have odd cycles in a bipartite graph, so you increase paths by 2 (4-6-8....) but I got the idea!

Comment: thnx mate! this helps both of us.